# Cannot read property '_intl' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I use `mat-paginator` from Angular(Material) 12, which helps me implement the pagination feature. Besides pagination, I also would like to customize the label in the pagination from "**Items per page**" to "**Foo per page**"

[image]

My first implementation is following

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'Foo per page';
  }
}
```

This one does not work and it shows the error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_intl' of undefined

I made the second try with the following implementation

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'Foo per page';
  }
}
```

Then it works like a charm!

Why do I need to set `{static: true}` for `@ViewChild` to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You should put it in NgAfterInit:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'Foo per page';
}
```

Because at the moment of ngOnInit is undefined. you can check [here](https://upmostly.com/angular/what-does-the-static-property-on-viewchild-do)